# set image visible for parents in expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a expandiblelistview with my own adapter, in the parents row i have 3 images invisibles and 3 textviews.

In activity i have a String[][] with data. 
Depending of data i want to set the images to visible.

Im tryin to do it:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = newGroupView(isExpanded, parentView);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        ponIconos();
        return v;
    }

    private void ponIconos() {

        ImageView drCandado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icono_candado);
        ImageView drOjos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icono_ojo);
        ImageView drUrgente = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icono_urgente);

        for(int i =0; i<ArrayServicios.size();i++){
            if (sIconos[i][0] != "null")
                drUrgente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (sIconos[i][1] != "null")
                drCandado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (sIconos[i][2] != "null")
                drOjos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
        }
    }
```

But it crashes nullpo..
Logcat:

```
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.reparalia.movilidad.ListadoServicios$adaptadorLista.ponIconos(ListadoServicios.java:532)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.reparalia.movilidad.ListadoServicios$adaptadorLista.getGroupView(ListadoServicios.java:520)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1617)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1401)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1405)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 08:44:01.066: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any other way?

**Solution**

```
/************************************************************************/
        /********************* Metodo que GENERA LA VISTA DE LOS PADRES ****************/
        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition,
                final boolean isExpanded, final View convertView,
                final ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {
                v = newGroupView(isExpanded, parent);
            } else **{
                v = convertView;
            }
            llenaPadre(v, padreDesde.get(groupPosition), padreDesde,
                    padreHasta, groupPosition);
            return v;
        }
        /********************* Metodo que rellena las filas padres ****************/
        private void llenaPadre(View v, Map<String, ?> map,
                List<? extends Map<String, ?>> datosPadres, int[] padreHasta2,
                int groupPosition) {
            ImageView drCandado = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.icono_candado);
            ImageView drOjos = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_ojo);
            ImageView drUrgente = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.icono_urgente);
            int len = padreHasta2.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(padreHasta2[i]);
                if (v != null) {
                    String texto = (String) map.get(cabecerasPadres[i]);
                    tv.setText(texto);
                    if (sIconos[0][groupPosition] != null)
                        if (drUrgente != null)
                            drUrgente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (sIconos[1][groupPosition] != null)
                        if (drCandado != null)
                            drCandado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (sIconos[2][groupPosition] != null)
                        if (drOjos != null)
                            drOjos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }**
        }
```

Comment: i edit my question with logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is , you are missing the view reference here. When you do a find view by Id, within a adapter you have to refer the item based on the view you have inflated. In your case the "convertView". Try like this, Pass the convertView objetc through ponIcons() and refer your widgets there.

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = newGroupView(isExpanded, parentView);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        ponIconos(convertView);
        return v;
    }

    private void ponIconos(View convertView) {

        ImageView drCandado = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icono_candado);
        ImageView drOjos = (ImageView)convertView. findViewById(R.id.icono_ojo);
        ImageView drUrgente = (ImageView)convertView. findViewById(R.id.icono_urgente);

        for(int i =0; i<ArrayServicios.size();i++){
            if (sIconos[i][0] != "null")
                if(drUrgente!=null)
                drUrgente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (sIconos[i][1] != "null")
                if(drCandado!=null)
                drCandado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (sIconos[i][2] != "null")
                if(drOjos!=null)
                drOjos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Return null too, in the same line

Comment: can you post that line as a comment now?

Comment: This works. I edit with my finally code for help anyone. But your anwser is true. Thanks